# Ternary Unwrapping in swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, ternary-operator, unwrap

In swift i'm using this code:

```
var categories: Results<Category>? //Realm dataType

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let categories = categories, !categories.isEmpty {
        return categories.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

I'm now looking to structure the code for my tableView as a ternary operator but don't know quite how to do this. I found the following page: 
https://dev.to/danielinoa_/ternary-unwrapping-in-swift-903 but it's still unclear to me.

What i tried is:

```
return categories?.isEmpty ?? {($0).count} | 1
```

or

```
let result = categories?.isEmpty ?? {($0).count} | 1
return result
```

but both giving errors. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: just shorten my code :)

Comment: Why return 1 if the array is nil? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: I always want to return a row in my tableView. If my array doesn't contain any items, the cell functions like a placeholder. The standard value of the cell then is "please add items"

Comment: The code example you provided requires the `??` and `|` infix operators to be implemented specially, which is not obvious when first skimming the blog post. While the resulting code is elegant, I prefer the native `Optional.map()` solution provided below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of ternary you could use `Optional.map` to make it even simpler:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.map { $0.count } ?? 1
}
```

Or mixing `Optional.map` and ternary to achieve what you I think are trying to achieve:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.map { !$0.isEmpty ? $0.count : 1 } ?? 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. ! i didn't know about "map". Could you explain a bit because i'm a bit confused.

categories.map unwraps the optional, then i check if the unwrapped value is not empty. If not empty i return the count of the value, if it is empty, i return 1, but what does the last part do ? from ?? 1

Comment: Your `categories` are Optional, so it could have some value or not. There are three cases to check in this case: 1. `categories` are nil, 2. `categories` are not nil but `isEmpty = true`, 3. `categories` are not nil and `isEmpty = false`. The last part you are asking about is to make sure to display the proper value in case number 1.

Comment: i see, perfect ! thanks for the solution and explanation ! much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Return 1 for nil and empty array , otherwise the value of `count`

```
return (categories?.count ?? 1) + (categories?.isEmpty ?? false ? 1 : 0)
```